# Hibernate Search index embedded map

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I'm having some issues with indexing embedded text entities with Hibernate search.
Since entities extend other entities that I can't change, using annotations is not feasible.

Thus I do the mapping using the programmatic API. However, Hibernate search doesn't index the embedded text entities.

Here's a short example of what the entity model looks like (stripped down for simplicity):

```java
@Entity
class Article {
  @Id
  private long uid; 

  private String articleNumber;

  @OneToMany ( mappedBy = "article" )
  @MapKey( name = "languageCode" )
  private Map<String, ArticleText> texts;
  ...
}

@Entity
class ArticleText {
  @ManyToOne
  private ArticleEntity article;      

  private String languageCode;
  private String someText;
  ...
}

@Entity
class SpecialArticle extends Article {
  private String someSpecialAttribute;
}
```

And here's an excerpt of the mapping:

```java
SearchMapping mapping = ...;
mapping.entity( SpecialArticle.class )
 .indexed()
   .property( "uid", ElementType.FIELD ).documentId()
   .property( "articleNumber", ElementType.FIELD ).field()
   .property( "someSpecialAttribute", ElementType.FIELD ).field()
   .property( "texts", ElementType.FIELD )
     .indexEmbedded().targetElement( ArticleText.class ).entity( ArticleText.class )        
       .property( "article", ElementType.FIELD ).containedIn()
       .property( "someText", ElementType.FIELD ).field();
```

The documentation isn't quite clear about using `.indexEmbedded().entity(...)`, but I have another embedded entity (a many-to-one association) which is only indexed using a similar mapping.

I suspect the texts are not mapped because of the map being used and Hibernate Search not being able to identify the property as a map. There is a `MapBrigde` as well as a `BuildInMapBridge` but they don't seem to be used when the mapping is built.

What might I be missing or where might be the error?

Btw, I do this in a Hibernate Search 4.0.1 and Hibernate 4.0.1 environment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I have found the solution. Since the documentation doesn't seem to be clear about it, I'll add it here for others to find.

The problem seems to be that the reference to the texts is a field of the super class `Article` and thus when `SpecialArticle` is being mapped, Hibernate Search seems to have difficulties.

To make it work, the mapping had to be changed to include the super class as well:

```
SearchMapping mapping = ...;
mapping.entity( SpecialArticle.class )
 .indexed()
   .property( "uid", ElementType.FIELD ).documentId()   
   .property( "someSpecialAttribute", ElementType.FIELD ).field();

//Map the super class directly, but don't call "indexed()"
mapping.entity( Article.class )
 .property( "articleNumber", ElementType.FIELD ).field()
   .property( "texts", ElementType.FIELD )
     .indexEmbedded().targetElement( ArticleText.class ).entity( ArticleText.class )        
       .property( "article", ElementType.FIELD ).containedIn()
       .property( "someText", ElementType.FIELD ).field();
```

What is strange is that the problem also occurs with `articleNumber` but not with `uid` (maybe because of `documentId()`).